# Why is this Spark SQL UDF slower than an RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have some expensive analysis I need to perform on a DataFrame of pairs of objects. The setup looks something like this.

```
# This does the expensive work and holds some reference data
# Expensive to initialize so done only once
analyze = Analyze()

def analyze_row(row):
    # Turn the row into objects and pass them to the function above
    foo = Foo.from_dict(row.foo.asDict(recursive=True))
    bar = Bar.from_dict(row.bar.asDict(recursive=True))
    return analyze(foo, bar)
```

When I apply `analyze_row` as a UDF like so

```
analyze_row_udf = udf(analyze_row, result_schema)
results_df = input_df.withColumn("result", analyze_row_udf).select("result.*")
```

it is empirically slower than applying it to an RDD like so

```
results = content.rdd.map(analyze_row)
results_df = spark.createDataFrame(results, schema=result_schema)
```

All other things being equal, the UDF version didn't seem to make progress in an hour, while the RDD version completely finished in 30 mins. The cluster CPU was maxed out in both cases. Same behavior was reproduced on multiple tries.

I thought DataFrames are meant to supersede RDDs, partially because of better performance. How come an RDD seems to be much faster in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrames can supersede RDDs where:

- There execution plan optimizations (here none can be applied).
- There low level optimizations used - off-heap memory, code generation (once again none are applied when you execute black box code outside JVM)
- Optimized columnar storage is used - (ditto).

Additionally passing data between contexts is expensive, and merging partial results requires additional operations. Also it more than doubles memory requirements.

It is hard to say why RDD are strictly faster in your case (there have significant improvements time, and you didn't provide a version) but I'd guess you hit some case border-case.

Overall, for arbitrary Python code `DataFrames` are not a better option at all. This might change a bit in the future, for vectorized operations backed with Arrow.